# rake 10.4.2 not getting installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails. Till now I was using cloud9 online development environment. Recently I thought of setting up the environment locally(Windows 8). I installed ruby on rails using the railsinstaller. Then i cloned my repository onto my system. There was no error to this point. When I run the command `bundle exec rake test` I get

```
    Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources.     
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then I tried installing rake with command `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'`. I got

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the ssl gem source with non-ssl as a temp solution:

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

From your log, it seems your server has some connection issues with the rubygems.org using SSL. That prevent you from instaling rake gem. 
As a workaround, you can do like this:

Open Gemfile, change `https://rubygems.org/` to `http://rubygems.org` and then issue command `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` again, good luck!